# Launching a pod in a different k8s cluster from a pod running in a different k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to launch a pod in K8s cluster named B from a pod running in K8 cluster C.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , run the pod in Cluster C with service account that has the authenitcation and authorization to launch pods in Cluster B , or embed some other credentails in the pod on cluster C that can do the same on cluster B , moreover , the API server of cluster B need to be accessable from pod on cluster C.

The simple way to test is run a pod on C with kubectl installed , and kubeconfig of cluster B , and just run the kubectl command.

It doesnt matter from where ( cluster , pod , container , machine) you are accessing the API server. You just need kubectl/client library with proper credentails.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's a hacky way but it's possible.

In addition, the guidelines are generally the same as in this answer:

[How I create new namespace in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901435/how-i-create-new-namespace-in-kubernetes/52901519#52901519)

In a pod in cluster B you can call:

```
$ kubectl apply -f  <your pod-definition>
```

Which creates a pod in cluster C, and `~/.kube/config` points to cluster C.

You can also set up a role and the whole RBAC and issue a `curl` from cluster B to cluster B.

```
$ curl -k -H -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                     -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
                     https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:6443/api/v1/namespaces/namespace/pods -d '
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "mypod"
        "namespace": "mynamespace",

    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
           {
              ...
           }
        ]
        ...
     }
}'
```

Or also use a library like [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) or/and [kubernetes-client/python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).